# Dictionary python specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code which scrape out everything from a specific web page, I now want to build a code which can help me to know the specific details, for example if I enter style id, it should give me the details related to it, or if I enter category, it should give me all the items in that category with their details. My code is:-

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="http://www.barneys.com/theory-andrejs-sweater-503900006.html#start=2"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links=soup.find_all("a")
img=soup.find(itemprop="image")
g_d4=soup.find_all("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"})
for item in g_d4:
    links_2=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men/'))
    pattern_2=re.compile("clothing/(\w+)")
    for link in links_2:
        match_1=pattern_2.search(link["href"])
        if match_1:
            print ("Category:- " + match_1.group(1))
            break
g_d1 = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "product-content"})
for item in g_d1:
  try:
      print ("\n\nBRAND:-" + item.contents[1].text)
  except:
      pass
  try:
      a_1=item.find("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"})
      a_2=a_1.text
      print a_2
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("TYPE:-" + item.find("h1",{"class":"product-name"},{"itemprop":"name"}).text+';')
  except:
      pass
  try:
      d2=item.find("div",{"class":"panel-body standard-p"})
      d3=d2.text
      p_id=re.findall(r'[0-9]{9}',d3)
      id_2=p_id[0]
      url_1 = 'http://recs.richrelevance.com/rrserver/p13n_generated.js?a=dbeab3c977a08905&ts=1434386243747&p='+str(id_2)+'&pt=%7Citem_page.rr1%7Citem_page.featured_item_0%7Citem_page.featured_item_1%7Citem_page.featured_item_2%7Citem_page.featured_item_3&u=mVBBR9wkG1PJ7zehLfmNXwzRp4WGMeDLG4M%3D&s=mVBBR9wkG1PJ7zehLfmNXwzRp4WGMeDLG4M%3D&cts=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.barneys.com&chi=%7Cmens-shirts-dress-classic&flv=18.0.0&rcs=eF4NyjEOgCAMBdCFybs0obQfyg28BhRIHNzU88v68sJxf881TDUSq6hYTimWomRGm9gkh9fPZo21olN3qbT3ogUYOcATzpgRP7a2EmY&l=1'
      r_1= requests.get(url_1)
      pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=p=)[0-9]+(?=&)')
      product_ids = pattern.findall(str(r_1.content))
      print ("DETAILS:- " + d3+';')
      print ("\nStyle ID:- " + id_2+';')
      print ("\nRecommended Product ID's:- ")
      print (','.join(i for i in product_ids))
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("\nURL:-" + img["src"]+';')
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("\nFull Price:-" + item.find("span",{"class":"price-standard"}).text+';')
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("\nDiscounted Price:-" + item.find("span",{"class":"price-sales"}).text+';')
  except:
      pass
g_d2=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"color-scroll"})
pattern_1=re.compile("pid=(\w+)")
for item in g_d2:
    links_1=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation'))
    for link in links_1[1:]:
        match=pattern_1.search(link["href"])
        if match:
            print ("\nProduct ID of other color:-")
            print (match.group(1))
```

Comment: You can add whatever you have to a custom string of html and then sift through that for specifics

Comment: I am really confused how to proceed, could you please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `findall()` and other BeautifulSoup methods so far? You can get the HTML for the elements with the specific id or other identifier that way. Then, look through that HTML and find what you need. If this is for multiple webpages, then find some similarities among them (ex. Some classes have the same types of information, etc.). You might be able to find information from others who have scraped the same website

Comment: With lists, you can look for the `<li>`, just look for tags which contain the information. HTML is already structured, so you just have to understand how the maker used that structure

Comment: Sorry if this is not helping

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl+f` function when doing `inspect element` on Chrome. That can give a general idea instead of experimenting with BeautifulSoup straight away

Comment: No, I want to do it in a simple way of storing everything as a "dictionary", and then entering a key and getting the values associated to it.

Comment: Do you want everything to be done programatically or are you willing to look through some information by hand, change it, then make it a dictionary?

Comment: programatically, lets say, I just enter a style id, the output I want is the all the details associated to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83141/discussion-between-vaibhav-sinha-and-ytpillai).

Answer (score 0):

I added a dictionary called `d`

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

d={}

url="http://www.barneys.com/theory-andrejs-sweater-503900006.html#start=2"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.find_all("a")

d["links"] = []

d["links"].append(("href", [link.get("href") for link in links]))
d["links"].append(("class", [link.get("class") for link in links]))

img=soup.find(itemprop="image")
d["img"] = []

d["img"].append([("alt", img.get("alt")), ("src", img.get("src")), ("itemprop", img.get("itemprop")), ("class", img.get("class")[0])]) #You will have to put d["img"]["0"] instead of d["img"]["alt"]



g_d4=soup.find_all("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"})
for item in g_d4:
    links_2=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men/'))
    pattern_2=re.compile("clothing/(\w+)")
    for link in links_2:
        match_1=pattern_2.search(link["href"])
        if match_1:
            print ("Category:- " + match_1.group(1))
            break
g_d1 = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "product-content"})
for item in g_d1:
  try:
      d["Brand"] = item.contents[1].text
      print ("\n\nBRAND:-" + item.contents[1].text)
  except:
      pass
  try:
      a_1=item.find("ol", {"class":"breadcrumb"})
      a_2=a_1.text
      d["a_2"] = a_2
      print a_2
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("TYPE:-" + item.find("h1",{"class":"product-name"},{"itemprop":"name"}).text+';')

      d["Type"] = item.find("h1",{"class":"product-name"},{"itemprop":"name"}).text
  except:
      pass
  try:
      d2=item.find("div",{"class":"panel-body standard-p"})
      d3=d2.text
      p_id=re.findall(r'[0-9]{9}',d3)
      id_2=p_id[0]
      url_1 = 'http://recs.richrelevance.com/rrserver/p13n_generated.js?a=dbeab3c977a08905&ts=1434386243747&p='+str(id_2)+'&pt=%7Citem_page.rr1%7Citem_page.featured_item_0%7Citem_page.featured_item_1%7Citem_page.featured_item_2%7Citem_page.featured_item_3&u=mVBBR9wkG1PJ7zehLfmNXwzRp4WGMeDLG4M%3D&s=mVBBR9wkG1PJ7zehLfmNXwzRp4WGMeDLG4M%3D&cts=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.barneys.com&chi=%7Cmens-shirts-dress-classic&flv=18.0.0&rcs=eF4NyjEOgCAMBdCFybs0obQfyg28BhRIHNzU88v68sJxf881TDUSq6hYTimWomRGm9gkh9fPZo21olN3qbT3ogUYOcATzpgRP7a2EmY&l=1'
      r_1= requests.get(url_1)
      pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=p=)[0-9]+(?=&)')
      product_ids = pattern.findall(str(r_1.content))
      print ("DETAILS:- " + d3+';')
      d["Details"] = d3.split(",")
      print ("\nStyle ID:- " + id_2+';')
      d["Style"] = ("ID", id_2)
      print ("\nRecommended Product ID's:- ")
      print (','.join(i for i in product_ids))
      d["RecommendedProductIDs"] = [i for i in product_ids]
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("\nURL:-" + img["src"]+';')
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("\nFull Price:-" + item.find("span",{"class":"price-standard"}).text+';')
  except:
      pass
  try:
      print ("\nDiscounted Price:-" + item.find("span",{"class":"price-sales"}).text+';')
  except:
      pass
g_d2=soup.find_all("div", {"class":"color-scroll"})
pattern_1=re.compile("pid=(\w+)")
for item in g_d2:
    links_1=soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/on/demandware.store/Sites-BNY-Site/default/Product-Variation'))
    for link in links_1[1:]:
        match=pattern_1.search(link["href"])
        if match:
            print ("\nProduct ID of other color:-")
            print (match.group(1))
```

Comment: can you help me with the part of the code, using the code which I have written. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you need? Do you have the information? I'm sorry, I'm not that great at actually using BeautifulSoup if that is what you need

Comment: Nope, I just want to build a dictionary code using all the  extracted items which I have done in my code, category,brand,style id,details,price. Such that when I run that code, it ask me "what do you want to search for"..and when I enter a style id or category, it shows me all the details related to it using dictionary.

Comment: All you need to do is make a dictionary like this `d = {}` and then add keys and information for each id/class `d["style"] = #info`

Comment: I am confused with this thing only, I want you you to please edit my code and tell me, you can use pastebin.com to send me the code, I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: I made a template for you, just save the info in the way I showed you. I'm sorry, but I cannot just edit the code and do it for you as I am not completely familiar with BeautifulSoup. Did you write this code?

Comment: Please respond to the chat